# Throwing a party when the bathroom door can't be properly closed

Tags: bathroom, door

I am planning to throw a party at my place. The problem is that the bathroom door is quite difficult to close: the door knob is loose and hence I don't dare pulling it to close the door. Instead I need to pull the small latch under the knob quite vigorously. I can't lock the door either since the door is not correctly aligned with the wall (maybe the wood is a bit swollen because of the humidity).

I guess there are two problems: the loose knob and the door misalignment. However I don't have time to really fix either of them before my party. Needless to say that I don't want my friends to feel uncomfortable, especially since the bathroom is just next to the main room where most guests will be staying. I doubt people would appreciate leaving the door partially open when they use the bathroom!

What would be the easiest way to solve that unfortunate situation?

**Edit about my situation:**
I'm renting the apartment so I can't really drill holes in the wall nor the door.

Answer (score 8):

#### If your door opens to the *inside*:

Go to your local big-box or home store and pick up a **flip door lock** (aka flip-action lock) and install it just above the doorknob. It costs less than US$5.00 and can be installed in a few minutes.

This will hold the door shut when engaged (even if the door does not physically latch closed). It installs on the *inside* of the door jam, so it will not create any noticeable damage to your door once it is repaired. And most importantly… it should be reasonably self-explanatory so you don't have to instruct everyone how to use your restroom <grin>.

Product Search: [**flip lock**](https://www.google.com/search?q=flip+lock&client=firefox-b-1&source=lnms&tbm=shop)

[image]

#### If you door opens to the *outside*:

I would suggest something more like *this* (for minimum damage and installation time):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: perhaps he lives in rented accommodation and can't modify?  The tools needed to fit those are pretty much what you need to fix the handle. Treat the cause, not the symptom

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly it. I'll edit my post such that it is more clear. (Oh and actually I'm a woman)

Comment: @Trabool your post was totally gender-neutral but I apologise. My answer to you would have been the same had I known.My daughters are taught how to use tools.

Answer (score 3):

### call your landlord

As you mentioned that the location is a rental, you should consult with the renter whenever problems arrive with the unit. This is equal parts a courtesy to the owner/operator and a right you generally have as a tenant to not live in a broken space (unless you have some other agreement)

Answer (score 2):

One option could possibly be to just remove door knob, and replace with a piece of rope through that hole. Tie a knot on either side, and you'll have door knobs not falling off, and something you can pull vigorously.

This is also not destroying the door, and when the landlord comes around he can replace the door knob properly.

In addition, depending on how much you can close the door initially, you might consider having a flip-over plaque  to indicate if the bathroom is occupied or vacant. Most (if not all) of your guests should respect such a sign.